# No row with the given argument - Hibernate, Java

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am using hibernate in my java dynamic project and since last week I am getting one exception called "No row with the given identifier exist[#entity(0)]. I found same problem asked earlier  and I did same as suggested but problem  persisted. I tried using "not-found=ignore" case as well but it doesn't work. Even the project is working fine @ Production but here @ development is quite disturbing. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this](http://ageekstory.blogspot.com/2009/06/hibernate-no-row-with-given-identifier.html) can help explain it.

Just a suggestion: whenever I get an error message of any kind, I immediately cut & paste it into a Google search to see what comes back.  It's highly unlikely that I'm the first person to encounter a problem.